# Drawer Layout gets cropped at bottom when QRCodeReaderView is inflated

Tags: android, view, zxing, materialdrawer

In my project I'm using [this material drawer lib](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) of version `5.0.0` and [this QR code reader lib](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView) of version `2.0.1`. XML layout has the following structure:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/include_qr_reader" />

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        ... 
        />

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

Here `@layout/include_qr_reader` is just a view:

```
<com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In my activity class first I'm checking camera permissions and if granted I just call `viewStub.inflate()`. In result my drawer gets cropped as seen in the image below:

[image]

After the view gets updated (some button clicked) the drawer gets back to normal.

And also LayoutInspector says all ok:

[image]

If you need more info on this case just let me know in the comments section.

### Question

*Why does my DrawerLayout gets cropped at the bottom when camera is active?*

### I've already tried:

- Changing layout params of drawer in code after `.inflate()`
- Changing layout params of qrreaderview in code after `.inflate()`
- Calling `.requestLayout()` and `.invalidate()` from `QRCodeReaderView`, `DrawerLayout` and `Activity.getWindow().getDecorView()`
- Calling `.requestLayout()` and `.invalidate()` of those views in `new Handler().post(() -> ...)`
- `viewStub.inflate().post(() -> drawer.getDrawerLayout().invalidate())`

Comment: The layout itself looks correct. also the view hierarchy, hmmm I can only assume that perhaps the `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` for the camera preview is in the wrong level. does that QR code reader lib offer anything to switch between those?

Comment: @mikepenz no. It just offers a custom view that I should use.